# Is it possible to save in Binding of Isaac?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac

I know this is kind of silly but is it possible to save current progress?  So far I've been leaving the game running so when I return I can attempt to finish the level but it would be nice to just save.

I haven't seen an option in the GUI to save or reload but I figure i'd ask the community.  Maybe I am missing something.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No, it's not possible.

The point of the game is to keep short playing sessions where death is a permanent threat. Not having the player be able to save the game both gets across this gameplay idea, and as a nice side effect it keeps players from abusing savegame files or saving mechanics (for example, save and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> task manager quit the game, and restart).

That said, the overall progress is always saved, such as your general stats and unlocks.

Comment: I simply haven't devoted more than 15 minutes at a time to the game as my daughter likes to interrupt me :)

Comment: @heishe - I played this game for a few hours and I didn't notice any permanent stats boosts.. I always seem to start with a clean default version of Isaac. Are this permanent boosts so rare?

Comment: By stats I just mean those overall stats that you can look at, like how often you died so far, etc.

Comment: aaaah, so basically there is no option to boost your character somehow and play the next run with that boosted, stronger character? you start over with default character speed/hp/dmg on each new play?

Comment: It's been a while since I played, but I think so, yes.

Comment: A suspend mode would be awesome.

Answer (score 9):

Unlocked characters, stats, and suchlike are saved automatically, but you can't save your progress in a specific session. The game is rather short, and randomly generated each time, so this shouldn't really be a problem.

You play until you die, win, or quit. Then you start over.